# Quantum circuits for multiply-accumulation

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, multiplication

Classically, multiplication can be done in $O(n \ \lg(n) \ 8^{\lg^* n})$ steps on a multi-tape Turing machine via [Fürer's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm). Using that algorithm, combined with uncomputing, you can make a quantum [multiply-accumulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) circuit with the same bound: $O(n \ \lg(n) \ 8^{\lg^* n})$ gates.

But quantum circuits have more options available. Maybe they can multiply in some better faster way, instead of just copying the classical algorithm.

Are there more efficient quantum circuits for multiply-accumulating?

Comment: I found the paper [A quantum multiply-accumulator](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-013-0715-5), but its accumulator uses classical inputs and is not optimized for gate count at all.